# Old paperback kids' novel involving a boy and girl living underwater

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember reading a used, older paperback when I was a kid, so it was before the 80s/90s. It was like a vintage scholastic-type novel - thin paperback. I feel like the title had something to do with a (then) futuristic year - like 2000 or 2020, something like that.

What I remember is a boy living underwater and maybe a girl too. At one point, I think a big sea turtle helps them swim and it’s where I learned the term “the bends” - I think maybe the girl suffers it. I’d like to read it again!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. When you say that the boy lived underwater, do you mean that he lived in an underwater habitat? If so, did the girl live there too? And did anyone else?

Comment: Thank you! As far as I remember yes there was a city or settlement underwater. I think she did too? But maybe not since rising to the surface was a problem for her? I don’t remember much sadly :(

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a long shot, but could be *Crisis on Conshelf 10* by Monica Hughes?

Short version:

The boy is visiting his cousin who lives in an underwater colony, deep enough to require a decompression stop when returning to the surface. Events happen and he needs to escape to the surface - the colony has trained dolphins to help aid evacuations and he hitches a lift to the surface but winds up suffering the bends and needs medical assistance at the end of the story.

Deviations then would be it's the boy not the girl who gets the bends and it's a dolphin not a turtle that helps with the swim but otherwise major points seem to match.

The book had multiple releases in both hard- and soft-cover.

Answer (score 0):

It is also a long-shot, but  could this be one of the [Willard Price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_Price) "[Adventure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adventure_series_(Willard_Price))" series. These are not SciFi, but rather adventure stories set on Earth. They describe the adventures of Hal and Roger Hunt, who are a pair of teenage explorers and adventurers who travel the world collecting rare and exotic animals for their father.

There are a number of stories that take place in the on/in oceans and involve diving, including one where the boys live in an undersea village and where they learn to dive (including deep-sea). I don't recall any with women/girls involved, but there are a couple with turtles and a couple that mention/learn about the bends.